# Should it be "journey by train" or "in the tomorrow morning"?

Tags: grammaticality

> We reserved tickets for a journey on train for the tomorrow morning with my sisters and me.

Should it be a journey by train or in the tomorrow morning?

Answer (score -1):

You're correct that it's a "journey **by** train". This is certainly confusing, since a "journey **on** foot" would be a journey taken by walking; I believe "on foot" is the only mode of transport that uses "on".

---

"For the tomorrow morning" is also incorrect. It's simply "for tomorrow morning". Generally, omit "the" in this phrase if the specified time is unambiguous; "the" is used to identify a time relative to something else.

Examples:

- "we reserved tickets for Monday" means "we reserved tickets to be used on the Monday which is about to come".
- "we reserved tickets for the following Monday" means "we reserved tickets to be used on the Monday after whatever I was just talking about".
- "we reserved tickets for the day after tomorrow".

---

Finally, "we reserved tickets with my sisters and me" is using the wrong conjunction. "We reserved tickets **for** my sisters and me" is correct. Note that this makes the sentence use the word "for" three times consecutively, so it reads a bit poorly; in conversation (where two consecutive "for"s sound OK) I might rephrase as:

> We reserved train tickets for tomorrow morning for my sisters and me.